# Python class scope and threading

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, scope, thread-safety, python-multithreading

I am a little confused about python class scope. Also about its relation to threading. Below is a minimal working example. I created an instance of `B` and passed it to the instance of `A`.

1. The way I understand it `A` should be making its own local copy of `B_instance`. Apparently this is not happening since every time I modify an attribute of `B_instance` by any imaginable means I see the change in both `A_instance` and `B_instance` (prints 1 -6). Does this mean that `A_instance.other_class` is regarded as global? Is there a way to make `A_instance.other_class` local? so that modifying it wouldn´t change `B_instance itself`.
2. The second part of the question is related to threading. I know that access to class attributes is not thread-safe so I am using locks. However if you take a look at the print statements I would expect "lock released" to be printed before "modified by main thread". What am I missing? Both locks seem to be locking something else because apparently the lock in the main thread can be acquired even though the one in `A_instance` is still in effect. I feel like this contradicts my findings from the first part.
3. Is it possible to acquire a lock for the whole object, not just its attribute or method?

---

```
class A:

    def __init__(self, other_class):
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.other_class = other_class

    def increment_B(self):
        self.other_class.B_attr_1 += 1

    def set_B(self):
        self.other_class.B_attr_1 = 10

    def thread_modify_attr(self):
        self.lock.acquire()
        self.other_class.B_attr_1 = "modified by class"
        time.sleep(10)
        self.lock.release()
        print("lock released")


class B:

    def __init__(self):
        self.B_attr_1 = 0


if __name__ == "__main__":

    B_instance = B()

    A_instance = A(B_instance)

    print("1:", B_instance.B_attr_1)

    A_instance.other_class.B_attr_1 += 1
    print("2:", B_instance.B_attr_1)

    A_instance.other_class.B_attr_1 = 10
    print("3:", B_instance.B_attr_1)

    A_instance.increment_B()
    print("4:", B_instance.B_attr_1)

    A_instance.set_B()
    print("5:", B_instance.B_attr_1)

    B_instance.B_attr_1 = 0
    print("6:", A_instance.other_class.B_attr_1)

    lock = threading.Lock()

    t = threading.Thread(target=A_instance.thread_modify_attr)
    t.start()
    print("thread started")

    print(B_instance.B_attr_1)

    lock.acquire()
    B_instance.B_attr_1 = "modified by main thread"
    lock.release()

    print(B_instance.B_attr_1)
    print("done")

    t.join()
```

Results:

```
1: 0
2: 1
3: 10
4: 11
5: 10
6: 0                                                                                                             
thread started                                                                                                      
modified by class                                                                                                          
modified by main thread
done
lock released
```

If somebody knows about some good place to read about details of python scoping I would appreciate it.

Comment: Did you find my answer helpful? [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No. When you create an instance of B and pass that to the A constructor, a *reference* to the same B instance is passed. There is no copy made. If you want that, you would have to make a copy of it yourself. One way is with [`copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/copy.html?highlight=copy%20deepcopy#copy.deepcopy) (although note that there are certain types that cannot be copied -- a `threading.Lock` instance being one of them). Essentially the new reference (that you store in A's `self.other_class`) is another name for the same instance.
2. The reason your two blocks of code are able to execute at the same time is that you have created *two different locks*. You create one in the class A constructor -- that one is being locked/unlocked by `thread_modify_attr`. The other one is being created in the main thread code just before the sub-thread is created and is being locked and unlocked by the main thread. If you want the two to utilize the same lock, pass (a reference to) the lock into the thread function as an argument. Because they are not the same lock, there is nothing preventing both threads from executing concurrently.
3. Locks can protect whatever you want them to protect. It's the responsibility of your code to determine what is protected by the lock. That being said, you *could* create a lock in the constructor of your class. Then whenever anything references the class instance, you could use the lock associated with the instance to synchronize access. A common pattern is to centralize control of object resources within the class. So that an outside agent simply asks the object to do something (by calling one of its methods). The object then uses the lock internally to protect its data structures.

Python scoping rules are described [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/executionmodel.html)

Comment: Both the question and this answer is so clear and of good quality that I feel it's a shame they haven't attracted more attention.

Answer (score 0):

**Just an extension to @Gil's answer above**

1. You can see a visual explanation of how Python deals with your classes, their instances and the references to them on [this PythonTutor snippet](http://shorturl.at/hkL07) I created for you.

Lock can operate as a context manager, so you can use it in a with statement, and it gets released automatically when the with block exits for any reason (e.g. an exception).

```
def thread_modify_attr(self):
    with self.lock:
        self.other_class.B_attr_1 = "modified by class"
        time.sleep(10)
    print("lock released")
```

**Note:** In case the link above has gone dead, just go to [PythonTutor.com](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) directly and copy and paste this modified version of your code. The only change is that I removed everything to do with Threading, as that is not supported by the site.

```
class A:

    def __init__(self, other_class):
        self.other_class = other_class

    def increment_B(self):
        self.other_class.B_attr_1 += 1

    def set_B(self):
        self.other_class.B_attr_1 = 10


class B:

    def __init__(self):
        self.B_attr_1 = 0


if __name__ == "__main__":

    B_instance = B()

    A_instance = A(B_instance)

    print("1:", B_instance.B_attr_1)

    A_instance.other_class.B_attr_1 += 1
    print("2:", B_instance.B_attr_1)

    A_instance.other_class.B_attr_1 = 10
    print("3:", B_instance.B_attr_1)

    A_instance.increment_B()
    print("4:", B_instance.B_attr_1)

    A_instance.set_B()
    print("5:", B_instance.B_attr_1)

    B_instance.B_attr_1 = 0
    print("6:", A_instance.other_class.B_attr_1)

    print(B_instance.B_attr_1)
    print("done")
```